# What would the sets of the edges and vertices would look like for the graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm given problem to determine whether a graph has an Eulerian cycle, but I am having trouble "building" the sets for the graph's edges and vertices:

$$
\begin{align}
& V = \{(i, j) \text{ | } i, j \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}
\\\\
& E = \{((i, j),(k, l)) \text{ | } i = k, j \neq l \text{ or } j = l, i \neq k \}
\end{align}
$$

There's no info what $m$ and $n$ are supposed to be? Am I missing something or is the problem incomplete?
I'd like to "construct" the sets so I can use the statement below to solve the problem.

> A graph has an eulerian cycle iff every vertex is of even degree.

---

**Edit:** The "exact" wording of the problem is as follows:

> Problem 1: Find which of the following graphs have an Eulerien cycle:
>
> (1) vertices: all bit strings with length 7; each two vertices are adjacent if the Hamming distance of the strings is $\leq 2$
>
> (2) $ V = \{(i, j) \text{ | } i, j \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$
>
> $E = \{((i, j),(k, l)) \text{ | } i = k, j \neq l \text{ or } j = l, i \neq k \}
> $

That's everything, it's actually in Bulgarian, but I tried to translate it as well as possible. No other info is given. I was about to start "trying" with different values for $n$ and $m$ and see what happens.

Comment: Likely $m$ and $n$ are just arbitrary fixed natural numbers.

Comment: For every possible value of $m$ and every possible value of $n$ you get a different graph. So you don't just have "a" graph. If you look more carefully at the wording of the problem you received, you might find clues about what it is that you're actually supposed to determine for what cases. You could edit the question to show the exact original wording of the problem it you want help interpreting it.

Comment: @DavidK I updated my question adding the "exact original wording" (I just translated it into English). I believe I could solve the first part myself, however I have no ideas regarding the second one.

Comment: Draw the graph for small values of $m$ and $n$ and then draw the edges. Part of learning this is to translate those definitions into a picture. As it stands, you are asking us to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a picture for $m=n=3$ will help:

[image]

Comment: @DavidK In the usual terminology of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), edges are taken to be undirected unless the word "directed" is used.  So no, it is not a separate edge.

Comment: @DavidK The OP's statement "A graph has an eulerian cycle iff every vertex is of even degree." would not be true for a directed graph.

Comment: I was thinking multigraph, but on second thought the notation could still only support two edges per pair of nodes and the question is not a good one. So maybe the question really is to explore the different values of $m$ and $n$.